# How to display the documentation of a method in NetBeans (Java) using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: java, netbeans, documentation

I searched around and didn't find anything. So how do I display the documentation of a method when the cursor is on the method name, using a keyboard shortcut? It's annoying when I can't see the method parameters etc. after I've finished typing the method.

Comment: I always right-click, then select "Show Javadoc" if the method is already written or use control space for autocomplete popup including documentation while entering the method name.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Choose Tools -> Options -> Keymap.
```

Find `Expand all javadoc` and set key for this.